# Why this integral equals to $\Gamma(4)10^4$

Tags: probability

I'm stuck with this equation:
$$\int_0^{\infty}y^3 e^{-\frac{y}{10}}~~dy=\Gamma(4)10^4.$$

In this equation, $\Gamma$ stands for Gamma function. I don't know where does $10^4$ come from. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Take $y\over10$ for the new variable and see where this gets you.

Comment: Just integrate by parts.

Comment: @IvanNeretin What if I change $dy$ to $d\frac{y}{10},$ is this follows $dy=10\cdot d\frac{y}{10}$? That's where I'm stuck with.

Comment: Well, yes, it works like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\frac{y}{10} = u \iff y = 10u \iff dy = 10\,du$

Then:

$$\int_0^{\infty}y^3 e^{-\frac{y}{10}}\,dy=\int_0^{\infty}(10u)^3 e^{-u}(10\,du) = 10^4\int_0^{\infty}u^{4-1} e^{-u}\,du = \Gamma(4)10^4$$

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by simply integrate by parts. However, I will give you a beautiful method for solving the problem. Let's introduce a variable $\alpha$ to the integral such that
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}dy\lim_{\alpha\to1}\;y^3e^{-y\alpha/10}=\lim_{\alpha\to1}\int_{0}^{\infty}dy\;y^3e^{-y\alpha/10}$$
The solution to the limit will be precisely the value of the integral. Now we know that
$$y^3e^{-y\alpha/10}=-10^3\frac{d^3}{d\alpha^3}e^{-y\alpha/10}$$
Now, the integral reads
$$-10^3\lim_{\alpha\to1}\int_{0}^{\infty}dy\frac{d^3}{d\alpha^3}e^{-y\alpha/10}$$
You can exchange the derivative and the integral, since the function is smooth (and they are both acting in different variables)
$$-10^3\lim_{\alpha\to1}\frac{d^3}{d\alpha^3}\int_{0}^{\infty}dye^{-y\alpha/10}=\lim_{\alpha\to1}\frac{d^3}{d\alpha^3}\frac{10^4}{\alpha}$$
Finally, you have only to derive three times the expression and to take the limit in order to get your result $\Gamma(4)10^4$